# Were there really 5x as many makkos at yam suf?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, yetziat-mitzrayim, agada-stories-legends, plagues-makkos, hands-fingers

Towards the end of the haggadah, there is a paragraph discussing how many makkos there were at yam suf:

> רבי יוסי הגלילי אומר- מנין אתה אומר שלקו המצרים במצרים עשר מכות ועל הים לקו חמישים מכות? במצרים מה הוא אומר "ויאמרו החרטמים אל פרעה אצבע אלהים היא". ועל הים מה הוא אומר "וירא ישראל את היד הגדלה אשר עשה יי במצרים וייראו העם את יי ויאמינו ביי ובמשה עבדו". כמה לקו באצבע- עשר מכות. אמור מעתה, במצרים לקו עשר מכות ועל הים לקו חמישים מכות."
>   Rabbi Yosi HaGlili says: From where do we know that the Egyptians were punished with ten plagues in Egypt and fifty at the sea? In Egypt what does it say "The magicians said to Pharaoh 'It is the **finger** of God'". And what does it say by the sea "The Israelites saw the great **hand** which God did in Egypt, and the nation feared God and believed in God and Moshe, his servent." How much were they punished with a runner-up 10 plagues. From here you can say, in Egypt they were punished with ten plagues and on the sea with fifty.

(Translation by me)

This logic seems very simple, but there is one problem: a "hand of God" is mentioned a few times in regard to the plagues as well! For example:
(Shemos 7:14)

> ונתתי את ידי במצרים
>   I put my hand in Egypt
>   (Shemos 13:9) 
>   ביד חזקה הוציאך 
>   He took you out with a strong hand
>   And even by the plague of pestilence itself it says (Shemos 9:3)
>   הנה יד יי הויה במקנך...
>   Behold God's hand is against your cattle...

So how can Rabbi Yosi HaGlili say that the plagues in Egypt were only a "finger" if the above three Pesukim say they were a "hand"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Haflaa (Rabbi Pinchas HaLevi Horowitz, av"d Frankfurt) [asks your question](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_The_Ten_Plagues?lang=bi&p2=Peirush_Hafla%27ah_on_Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_The_Ten_Plagues.18.1&lang2=bi). In summary he explains that really all **five fingers were used for the ten plagues, but only one "etzba" at a time**. So since for Kinim the 3rd plague the 2nd finger (etzba) was used, the thumb must have already been used for the first 2 plagues, 2nd finger 3rd and 4th plague 3rd finger 5th and 6th plague etc. until the every finger was used for the 10 plagues.

So really the hand that was used at the sea was the same hand used for the 10 Makkos.
But the hand **at the sea the "Yad Hagedola" all 5 fingers were used at the same time**. This can be explained:

"Five of you shall give chase to a hundred and a hundred shall give chase to ten thousands.”Leviticus 26:8 Commenting on this Rashi writes: “Is this then the correct proportions? Should it not have said and a hundred shall give chase to two thousand? However one cannot compare the few who keep the Torah to the many who keep the Torah.” This is so because the ones who keep the Torah help one another. 100:10,000 which is **when the many help each other they are 5 times stronger than the few** 5:100 (which is the same as 100:2,000).

So too Rabbi Yossi Hagellili learnt from the Blessings in Bechukosai that "Yad hachazaka" the strong hand at the sea where all the fingers were together helping each other, was 5 times stronger than the individual fingers on their own. **So the individual fingers made 10 plagues where as the collective hand made 50 plagues**

---

For those that  want to see the whole excerpt:
 אך קשה הא כתיב ונתתי את ידי במצרים וכתיב ביד חזקה הוציאך הרי דגם במצרים לקו ביד ועוד נראה דהא אצבע אלהים היא הוא מכת כנים ועיין פירש״י שם נמצא שאין הכתובים סותרים זא״ז די״ל שלקו בכל אצבע שתי מכות נמצא בגודל לקו שתי מכות דם צפרדע ובכנים לקו באצבע הסמוך לגודל ובו לקו ג״כ מכת ערוב וכך בכל אצבע שני מכות והיינו דכתיב ונתתי את ידי במצרים נמצא קשה על ריה״ג מנ״ל דעל הים לקו חמשה פעמים כמו במצרים ונראה לפרש ע״פ מה שאמרו חז״ל והביאו רש״י ז״ל בפסוק ורדפו מכם חמשה מאה כו׳ וכי כן הוא החשבון והנה לא היה צריך לומר אלא מאה שני אלפים ירדופו אלא אינו דומה חמשה שרודפים למאה רודפים דהיינו משום שהם מסייען זא״ז וכמ״ש בחידושי כתובות דף ה׳ אהא דקאמר שם גדול עשה לצדיקים יותר ממעשה שמים וארץ דאלו בשמים וארץ כתיב ידי יסדה ארץ וימני טפחה שמים ואלו במעשה צדיקים כתיב מקדש ה׳ כוננו ידיך והיינו שני ידים שמסייעין זא״ז וא״כ ה״נ דאף בידו יסדה ארץ היינו יד שמאל הרי דגם מעשה שמים וארץ היה בשתי ידים אלא אינו דומה שהיה כל אחת ביד אחת ולא הי׳ מסייעין זא״ז משא״כ במעשה צדיקים כוננו ידיך והיינו שתי ידים שמסייעין זא״ז וא״כ ה״נ כיון דביד לקו בכל היד יחד אינו דומה למכת מצרים שהיה בכל אצבע בפני עצמה ולא היה מסייעין אצבעות זה לזה וכיון דמצינו גבי ורדפו מכם חמשה מאה במרובין המסייעין זא״ז הוא כפול חמשה פעמים שהרי לא היה צריך לומר אלא שני אלפים וכתיב רבבה דהוא עשרת אלפים למד ריה״ג מזה דעל הים לקו חמשה פעמים כמו במצרים

Comment: then why does it say "hand" by pestilence, when it was only the first half of the third finger?

Comment: @Loani The Haflaa's answer is saying every mention of Yad except for by Yam Suf where it  says *Yad Hagedola* means individual fingers. It is true that with Dever *Yad*  means one (or half) a finger from the hand,because otherwise there would be no explanation why all 10 plagues are called *Yadi* and yet Dever is also Yad. So thats why there is no other way of explaing othe than saying Dever had to be part of a hand i.e a tenth of the hand that performed all 10 plagues. Please consider the time i have taken and explaining this answer

Comment: also of interest is the opinion that each plague was accompanied by pestilence. according to that, it would explain why it says hand by pestilence.